# Can I get a better results with my Canon 50d?

Tags: image-quality, canon-50d

[image]I'm using my 50d to take photos of carpets and objects at home.  Some of the light is coming from the window while other from a halogen lamp.

My config is: Shutter speed 160 - Flash on - iso 1600 - lens 70-135mm.

I'm not getting a good result as a quality image: if I zoom the image I see lots of noise.  Are there any suggestions to make it better
the image Full size : [Here](http://i215.photobucket.com/albums/cc237/kurapika89/IMG_7022_zpsa787bb2b.jpg)

Comment: Please add some example photos showing the issues you're having.

Comment: Done .. as you can see, you can't see details when you Zoom the image.

Comment: Can you add some more information about how you took the photograph please - what ISO were you using, what format is the image file, and please could you also post the full image for comparison? The more we know, the more likely we are to be able to help.

Comment: i added a link to the Full size and iso ;

Comment: Are you _trying_ to take photos of carpets and home objects, or are you using them as test cases?

Comment: I'm trying to take photos of objects ... i'll use That photos for sure

Comment: doesn't look like it's well focused.  Nothing in the frame to really focus easily on.  I'd suggest you place some newspaper or something with sharp lines on it to help the camera focus.  Lock focus, remove paper or other focusing aid, then take picture. lack of focus seems to be a bigger problem than noise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **if I zoom the image I see lots of noise.**

I associate noise with high ISO and poor lighting.

The EXIF info in the full-size JPG contains the following information

- 1/160 second exposure
- f:4.5 aperture
- ISO 2000
- flash fired
- manual exposure
- manual white balance.

> **Are there any suggestions to make it better**

I think you'll get better images if you can get a lot more light onto the subject, however I'd try the following

- use a sturdy tripod (if you aren't already)
- use a timer or remote to trigger the shot
- set ISO low (100)
- set aperture to f8 to reduce the effect of any focusing problems
- set the camera to aperture priority
- let the camera determine exposure time (it will be very long)
- disable the built-in flash
- light the subject as strongly and evenly as you are able

  - use better hotshoe flashgun or studio lights if you have or can borrow or buy?
- take some shots with autofocus, then try a few manual focus variations

  - in focus and just out of focus either side (in case viewfinder is out of alignment)
- try a different lens if you have one (e.g. a standard prime rather than a zoom)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for .. i'll try this for sure 
Thank you so much.

Comment: I would also ensure you shoot in raw format and convert to JPG in dedicated image editing software such as Lightroom or Photoshop. When using the camera's built-in JPG compressor you are ceding control over the final image quality to the camera.